# Refactoring Switch Statements to If Statements

Tags: visual-studio

I currently have a lot of cases in a switch statement, and I would like to convert all of them to if statements. Other than changing each one by hand, is there a more convenient way of doing this? I'm using C# in Visual Studio Community Edition 2013, and I'm open to use any free third party tools.

Comment: I guess No, you have to change each one by hand

Comment: ReSharper can do this for you. But that's a third party tool. What version of visual studio? 2015? 2017? **If** there is an inbuilt solution it may matter which one you use.